# $http GET Receiving Empty Body

Tags: c#, angularjs, get

I have a GET method in angularjs that receives data from an API controller in C#. The controller is returning the data and the $http get method is receiving a response, but the response content body is empty.

My HttpGet API controller function:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/LandingPage/GetByDate")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    try
    {
        var startDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate);
        var endDateParam = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate);

        var confirmData = m_databaseObject.Database.SqlQuery<PageModel>("[dbo].[GetPageData] @startDate,@endDate", startDateParam, endDateParam).ToList();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, confirmData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"Error occured {e.Message} {startDate:yyyy-MM-dd} {endDate:yyyy-MM-dd}");
    }
}
```

The object I want to return:

```
public class PageModel
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int? FirstTotal { get; set; }
    int? FisrtInitial { get; set; }
    int? FisrtApproval { get; set; }
    int? SecondTotal { get; set; }
    int? SecondInitial { get; set; }
    int? SecondApproval { get; set; }
    int? Validated { get; set; }
    int? NotSettled { get; set; }
}
```

The GET method:

```
this.getLandingPage = function ($scope) {
    $scope.error = "";
    $scope.message = "";
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: apiName + "LandingPage/GetByDate?startDate=" + $scope.StartDate + "&endDate=" + $scope.EndDate,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        if (data.length === 0)
            $scope.message = "No Data found";
        else {
            $scope.LandingPageData = data;
        }
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.LandingPageData = null;
        if (error)
            $scope.error = error.Message;
        else
            $scope.error = "Data services may not be running, Please check!";
    })
}
```

My `confirmData` variable in my controller contains data when the function returns. My angularjs GET method returns success with `data.length` equal to 1, but there are no values contained in `data`.

Can anyone shed some light on why my data is not being transferred properly?

Comment: What's inside data? Did you try `data.data`?

Comment: `data` contains an object array of size 1 with an empty object

Comment: Have you debugged your controller and ensured confirmData actually has a value?

Comment: Yeah. The `PageModel` object contains data when the controller returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my `PageModel` class variables needed to be declared as public in order to pass the data from the controller.

Changing the `PageModel` class to this worked:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? FirstTotal { get; set; }
    public int? FisrtInitial { get; set; }
    public int? FisrtApproval { get; set; }
    public int? SecondTotal { get; set; }
    public int? SecondInitial { get; set; }
    public int? SecondApproval { get; set; }
    public int? Validated { get; set; }
    public int? NotSettled { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return JSON instead `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/LandingPage/GetByDate")]
public JsonResult GetByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    try
    {
        var startDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate);
        var endDateParam = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate);

        var confirmData = m_databaseObject.Database.SqlQuery<PageModel>("[dbo].[GetPageData] @startDate,@endDate", startDateParam, endDateParam).ToList();

        return new JsonResult() { Data = confirmData , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

On client side your data should be placed in response `data` property. In your case it should be:

`data.data`

But please try to use `then` function intead`success` function:

```
.then(function (data) {
        var result = data.data;
    });
```

Even you can avoid `JsonResult` and use `string`. Serialize your model into JSON string and return string.

Comment: I tried using JsonResult and I am having the same problem.

Comment: @KevinK. Try to use `then` instead `sucess`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the data is nested under the `data` property.

```
.success(function (resp) {
    if (resp.data.length === 0)
        $scope.message = "No Data found";
    else {
        $scope.LandingPageData = resp.data;
    }
})
```

Comment: When I try this I get `resp.data` as undefined.

Comment: What do you see as the response in the network console?

Comment: The response code is 200 and the response body is `[{}]`

Comment: Have you debugged your controller and ensured confirmData actually has a value?  You may try to just return an explicitly defined array and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular are you using? From 1.6 .success is deprecated:

- [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

And, any specific reason why you are setting the Content-type header? You may use a simpler way:

```
return $http.get(url: apiName + "LandingPage/GetByDate?startDate=" + $scope.StartDate + "&endDate=" + $scope.EndDate, ).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

And then define your callback functions separately.